# c++ press enter to end program remove the press any key to continue

Tags: cin

I am trying to get the ending to be like this

```
    Enter your choice -->  f

    Program ending

    Press Enter to end -->
```

but instead i am getting this

```
Enter your choice -->  f

Program ending

Press enter to end -->Press any key to continue . . .
```

this is my brief code for the ending. basically I need to remove the "press any key to continue: from the ending I searched the forum and found and PrintF statement but I have not learned that yet so i need a simpler way. any help will be appreciated

```
        case 'f':
        case 'F': cout << "Program ending" << endl << endl;
                cout << "Press enter to end -->";
                cin.get();

                return 1;

            break;

        default: 
            cout << choice << " is an invalid value. " << endl;

        }
```

Comment: It depends on the compiler. What compiler do you use? It also depends on the IDE that you use.

Comment: i am using microsoft visual studio 2012

Comment: How about you run your code with F5 instead of ctrl + F5?

Comment: Or could you try to right click your project, then on the option list -> Properties -> Configuration Properties > Linker > System -> property SubSystem -> blank (yes, literally select the blank option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code (or the IDE you are using to launch it, perhaps) is an awful `system("pause");`. Find it, remove it, and never type those words again.

Comment: Could you do: System("pause >nul"); instead?

Comment: What would you want to? What if the person running your program has a home nuclear reactor and on their machine, "pause" pauses the cooling system? Are you writing a C++ program or not?

Comment: A person with a home nuclear reactor should be an overly-precautios one since any input might be lethal to the reactor system.

Comment: That was intended as a joke. For a more serious take, look [here](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html).